# RegEx to Match only 2 Consecutive Hash/Pound Signs

Tags: regex

Trying to figure out a Regular Expression to match **only** 2 consecutive "#". The regex should be able to detect a match within the following examples:

```
Example 1) firstword ##helloworld## lastword

Example 2) ##helloworld##
```

I currently have **^##.*##$** but it incorrectly matches to:

```
###helloworld###
```

Or it doesn't match when there's a string before or after 2 consecutive #:

```
firstword ##helloworld## lastword
```

Any feedback welcomed!!

Comment: Use `(?<!#)##(?!#).*?(?<!#)##(?!#)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lookarounds like

```
(?<!#)##(?!#).*?(?<!#)##(?!#)
```

*Details*:

- `(?<!#)##(?!#)` - a `##` string not immediately preceded nor followed with another `#` char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?<!#)##(?!#)` - a `##` string not immediately preceded nor followed with another `#` char

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! 

The regex you've provided works! Also, thank you for providing an explanation, it's extremely helpful.